# What is the proper unit for F1? Is it a percentage?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, precision-recall

F1-score is defined as
$$
F_1 = \frac{2PR}{P+R},
$$
where P is precision [0..1] and R is recall [0..1]. My question is simply, is it right to describe F1 as a percentage? As in "our final F1-score increased to 96.5%"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Precision and Recall are two measure that can be interpreted as *percentages*. Their arithmetic mean would be a percentage also. F1 score is actually the *harmonic mean* of the two; analogously it's still a percentage.

From a different perspective, you can think the unit as $U$, and substitute in the definition: 
$$F_1=2\frac{U.U}{U+U}\propto U$$

i.e. $U+U$ has unit $U$, $U.U$ has unit $U^2$, and $U^2/U$ has the unit $U$.

Comment: So the answer is YES?

Comment: Yes, it is a percentage.